# Why same width Select and Input tag in Safari is outrageously different while rendering

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, safari

I have a code where I am setting the width of `<input>` and `<select>` dynamically so that they look same (width-wise). I know there is ~5px width discrepancy between the two so if I set the width of `<input>` to 100px then I set `<select>` width to 105px; and this seems to work fine everywhere (chrome tends to be off by a pixel, but that is fine with me.) But I recently find out that 100px width  is not equal to 105px width  in Safari. In fact it is outrageously off. You can see it on following link:

http://jsfiddle.net/jH8qC/5/

Check it on chrome/firefox and then on Safari to see the difference.

Then I thought using the CSS to fix it using this

```
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
 box-sizing: border-box;
```

to maintain consistency. This works but not if I set width dynamically like seen here.

http://jsfiddle.net/jH8qC/6/

Any idea?

Comment: Do you use a CSS reset?

Comment: Yes I do. I have also tested it on normalize.css to be on a safe side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the width of a tag by running the width() function for that:

```
var foo = $("#example").width();
```

You can get the width of your inputs and your selects and then, if the desired value is 200 (for example), then you can run something like this:

```
$("#example").width(200);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem by turning off Safari's visual enhancements using the following CSS:

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
```

Answer (score 0):

Late answer :)
Try adding this to your CSS file:

```css
input, select {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -ms-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
}

::-webkit-datetime-edit,
::-webkit-datetime-edit-month-field,
::-webkit-datetime-edit-day-field,
::-webkit-datetime-edit-year-field {
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your jQuery is bad, here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/jH8qC/7/)

```
$(function() {
  $(".txt1").css({ width: '170px'});
  $(".sel1").css({ width: '175px'});
});
```

Comment: Tested on Safari for Windows 5.1.7

Comment: Although your solution works, I am still intrigued why .width() does not work in this case and only .css() does.

Comment: The difference between .css(width) and .width() is that the latter returns a unit-less pixel value (for example, 400) while the former returns a value with units intact (for example, 400px). The .width() method is recommended when an element's width needs to be used in a mathematical calculation. - [jQuery .width()](http://api.jquery.com/width/)

Comment: Well that is what the jQuery page says. But it seems the problem lies with the safari js engine with width() function. And it's a bug. I corrected my problem using outerWidth(). http://jsfiddle.net/jH8qC/10/

Comment: Check out your [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jH8qC/10/) in Google Chrome, now you have select fields about 4px longer than input fields, why do you don't want to use .css